# Swift change UICollectionView height when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm looking to do the following, see the 2 pictures below.
I have a `UICollectionView` and a `UILabel` on top of it (the green area).

I would like, when scrolling down, to decrease the height of the collection and increase the height of the UILabel scrolling up (similar with what safari does on iPhone with the search bar when scrolling up and down).
What I've tried is the following:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
    collectionView.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, collectionView.frame.origin.y-1, 375, collectionView.frame.height+1);
}
```

It's starting ok at first, the height is increasing, but suddenly the height of the `UICollectionView` gets smaller and then starts increasing again. And then it does the same

Here below I've displayed the results of `print(collectionView.frame)`

Is there a bug in my solution ?
Is there another way to achieve that ? Is something related to constraints ?

Thanks.

C.C.

```
(0.0, 174.0, 375.0, 493.0)
(0.0, 173.0, 375.0, 494.0)
(0.0, 172.0, 375.0, 495.0)
(0.0, 190.0, 375.0, 477.0)
(0.0, 189.0, 375.0, 498.0)
(0.0, 188.0, 375.0, 499.0)
(0.0, 187.0, 375.0, 500.0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add height constraint to your label *or* collectionView. Create an IBOutlet for that constraint and then change it in scrollViewDidScroll using the contentOffset as suggested by Michal.

Comment: Do you mean to add a constraint between my UICollectionView and the top of the screen ? And then increase/decrease it in scrollViewDidScroll ? Or between the UICollectionView and UILabel, in case which I only need to change the height of the UILabel ? Is this the solution?

Comment: No - if you are doing everything in constraints I would do the following. Have constraints between your label and the top of the screen as well as constraints on your label on either side. Add a height constraint to your label (which you are going to change). Add a constraint between the bottom of your label and UICollection view. Add constraints on either side of the UICollection view and its bottom. This way when you change the size of your label the height of your UICollection view will change as well.

Comment: I got it. Are you implying that I could do it without using the constraints ? Can you point this other way ?

Comment: I am saying - use the constraints. Don't bother with changing the frame of the UICollectionView yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution in your `scrollViewDidScroll` is omitting the direction of the scroll - basically you are saying: *move the collection view up and increase its size whenever the user scrolls*. But you are not saying whether it's up or down. I handle the direction by saving the last scrollView's `contentOffset.y` and then doing simple if:

```
if self.lastScrollViewContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
    // mumbo jumbo when scrolling up
} else {
    // mumbo jumbo when scrolling down
}
```

Also mind that this method is one of two that you should use to make it smooth and continuous. This method is called after the scrolling has happened:

> The delegate typically implements this method to obtain the change in content offset from scrollView and draw the affected portion of the content view.

But if you drag only half way you may find yourself in inconsistent state (I know this because I implemented similar thing), so also implement delegate method `scrollViewDidEndDragging` where you need to bear in mind that it may not decelerate and thus you'll need to add additional animation to make the UI consistent.

Comment: Yes, I did't handled the direction of the scroll because I saw the bug I was talking about. Not bad the idea about the contraints. I'll give it a try. I did't quite understood the last paragraphe. Can you please explain me a bit ? Thanks.

Comment: Phew I didn't see the edit, you have to comment again next time to get my attention! :-) The thing is, that the `scrollViewDidScroll` is called when scrolling has "happened", but it doesn't tell you whether the scrollView is still *in motion* - by implementing the `didEndDragging` you'll know that it will actually **stop** so you can handle if you scrolled only half way - the label would be half way shrunk/shown but not completely - this method will tell you if there will be any more scrolling. If not, you can add animation bringing the shrinking/showing to its completion.

Comment: Ok I got it. But actually I don't want to do the half screen animation. Basically I would have the top half screen with some labels, when scrolling I will hide everything except the title (like safari with the search bar)

Comment: I understand - but notice, that if you scroll slowly in Safari and bring it only half way and then *let go* - Safari animates the rest. It never leaves the UI in inconsistent state. Let's say you have min size 10 and max size 20. If you scroll up and shrink to 15, you wouldn't want to leave it like that, right? You would want to add the animation to make it to the final size 10.

Comment: Ah, you right. I did't think at that. Now I get what you mean ;).

Comment: I just implemented the solution, it does the job but it's not exactly what I want. Actually, when I scroll down, the collection must only increase height and start scrolling only when the UILabel will stop shrinking (if you know what I mean). Now is scrolling from the begining and increase height also which is not so great. Any idea how to "block" the UICollectionView scroll ?